# Can I work on github with opened source code on commercial project and how?

Tags: git, licensing, github

I really want to work with my project on GitHub and then Sell it (binary).

is that possible ?

what license I must to chose / create for it ?

Comment: I would argue this should either be reopened, and we ask the OP to give us a bit more detail, or we migrate it to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MatrixFrog OP ? Yes ... I'm still being in confusion about what license I should chose or how to compose it but maybe that is really offtopic question for stack-overflow.

Comment: OP means original post or original poster. In this case: you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any license restriction at http://help.github.com/terms/. But when you don't want the the source to be visible to anyone, you need to use a paid private repo.

**edit: license details**

For the license itself you need to use a license which is compatible to your business model. See the the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license_agreement#Comparison_with_free_software_licenses) for a start point. Even GPL does not forbid you to sell your software (but I wouldn't recommend it for commercial software). See [Reviewing Software License Agreements: A Licensee's Checklist](http://www.mbbp.com/resources/iptech/software_license.html)  for a more detailed view on the topic. Also when you decide to create your own license I suggest to contact a lawyer in the creation process.

Comment: Thank you. I don't care about opened source but can I sell program with opened source and what license I can use for it ?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to say "the source to be visible to anyone" rather than "the source to be open", just to avoid confusion...

Comment: @Mark , ohh... good point, but is there such licenses or I need to compose it myself ?

Comment: @Bjorky: you can still sell a program which you've released under [an Open Source license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/index.html), but you're obliged to make the source code available if you do so.  It's probably a bad idea to try to make up a license yourself unless you have training as a lawyer in the right fields.  This is probably [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/are-licensing-questions-on-or-off-topic-on-so), by the way...

Comment: Look at how David DeSandro of Metafizzy does it. I think more of us should follow his model. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/license.html